# What is a dry porter?

Tags: porter

A local brewpub describes one of its current beers as a "dry porter".  I got something else instead, so I didn't taste it.  I'm familiar with both porters and stouts (and the controversies over what the difference is), but what's a *dry* porter?  I found [a non-local example](https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/716/158378/) and [a recipe](https://www.brewersfriend.com/homebrew/recipe/view/297063/dry-porter), but neither describes the results enough for me to be able to tell what's "dry" about either.

Comment: It isn't listed as one of the six styles of porters at https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/styles/. It might like wine where "dry" means the opposite of "sweet". Some porters and stouts are kind of malty and sweet.

Comment: I suggest you move this to the homebrew stack where people with more beer knowledge hang out. https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @farmersteve but I'm not trying to *make* one; I want to understand what I'd be drinking.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Homebrew stack has some people that have very deep knowledge about beer. I am a moderator over there and even I've never heard about a Dry Porter. I can only assume they are using Alpha Amalyze enzyme to the mash to produce as dry as possible beer, but as a real style according to BJCP specifications, it is not a recognized style. http://brulosophy.com/2018/11/26/adding-enzyme-to-the-mash-vs-to-the-beer-in-brut-ipa-exbeeriment-results/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Eric mentioned in the comments, it is similar to wine, where you would expect a dry (or brut for sparkling) wine to have low to no residual sugars.   A dry beer (porter, in this case) is brewed specifically to ensure that the carbohydrates are all converted to fermentable sugars, which are then fermented as the term would indicate, leaving you with a higher alcohol beer with less residual sugar than an a traditional fermentation.